# word count limit in Angularjs(front page in bootstrap)

Tags: angularjs

i want to apply word count in angular js (eg in Text Box " I am Good " word count should be 3 ) and i also want to limit the word count 
please help

thanks in advance

Comment: you can find some good answers here https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/pull/194

Comment: Did you even give it any try?

Comment: please post some code. No one will write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I make a [Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/x2BW2iIIgcEycoxVqmG4) which counts words splitted by blank space.

**HTML**:

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
   Write in here!
   <input type="text" ng-model="myModel"/>
     <button ng-click="countWords(myModel)">Click Me</button>
   <h1 ng-show="wordCount">You have {{wordCount}} words!</h1>
</body>
```

**JS**:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){

  $scope.split = [];
  $scope.wordCount = 0;

  $scope.countWords = function(text){

    /*Split by Space*/
    $scope.split = text.split(/(\s+)/);

    /*Remove all the blank spaces*/
    for(var i=0; i<=$scope.split.length; i++){
      if($scope.split[i] === " "){
        $scope.split.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }

    /*Count Words*/
    $scope.wordCount = $scope.split.length;

  }
});
```

You can use this count to limit whatever you want. For instance, lets suppose you want to show "Hello There" only if `ng-model` has more than 3 words:

```
<div ng-show="wordCount>3">Hello There</div>
```

If you need to watch for how many words are contained in an input box, you simply attach a `$watch` task or use `ng-change` on that field, everytime it changes, you check how many words are in there, then you can deny more words to get written.

I hope I've been helpful.

Comment: $scope.countOf = function(text,count) {
            var s = text ? text.split(/\s+/) : 0; // it splits the text on space/tab/enter
              console.log(s.length);
             $scope.wc=s.length;
              if(s.length === count ){



              alert('limit exceded');
          //  text.substr(0,text.length);
              }
              return s ? s.length : '';



          };

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here$scope.countOf = function(text,count) {
        var s = text ? text.split(/\s+/) : 0; // it splits the text on space/tab/enter
          console.log(s.length);
           $scope.wc=s.length;
          if(s.length === count + 1){


          //  alert('limit exceded');
        //  text.substr(0,text.length);
          }
          return s ? s.length : '';
enter code here

      };
```

Comment: i have used this as i want live word count in text block but i am not able to limit it  means- i want agent to not be able to type after certain word count

Comment: please help ! me in to this

Comment: i also want to use this function in 3 text blocks and want to show the word count on each bl;ock which i am not able to do it        i have used {{wc }} to show the current word count , but same number is coming in all three text box